# In wordpress, how do I make the default archive function run?

Tags: wordpress

I have made a category archive page called category-blog.php.  However I need now to make this page a custom template for a page, the page works fine when simply browsing to mydomain.com/blog, because wordpress does some sort of query I guess before running this template. What I need to know is what is this query so I can run it before it hits my template page?  I need so that the pagination etc works  before looping through the results of the query.

Hope this makes sense, it's difficult to put down in words.

Comment: So are you wanting to copy this category template file and create a new page template for a specific page?

Comment: yes thats right, for the purposes of my displaying the category archive in the menu

Comment: Ahh, so the page thats currently your archive page works? but you need to now link this into the menu? are you using the "menus" under "appearance" in the admin area? if you are you can create a custom link and add that to your menu? instead of creating a new page!

Comment: @Marty No I know that I'm not.  I've inherited this massive wordpress site and they've used wp_list_pages and custom functions to create the menu and massive sub menu, so the easiest way is to create my archive page as a page so it works with what is already there.  Converting all that into a menu in the admin area would take hours.

Comment: Wish I could though, much simpler!

Comment: Ah I see... :| 
ok, so what to do is open your archive page, save it as a new page ie: page-archive.php then at the top of that page just before get_header(); is add the template tag to the page..

/* Template Name: New Archive Page */ then upload it. create your new page and assign the template to it?

Comment: yes but how do I then tell it to get an archive of category 'blog'?  With a page names archive-blog.php. this is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In your new template-page.php

```
<?php
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$wp_query = new WP_Query('cat=732&showposts=5&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?> etc...etc..
<?php endwhile; $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp; ?>

<?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?>
<?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?>
```

have a look here for other solutions
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-pagination-to-a-wp_query-loop

Comment: thanks for this info.  How do I get the next and prev navigation though in before the loop?  At the moment I have `<?php if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) : ?>
   <div id="nav-above" class="navigation">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
    <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?></div>
   </div><!-- #nav-above -->
  <?php endif;  ?>` which I need to come before the foreach loop that you have put.

Comment: on the archive page, unless you have loads and loads of posts, you shouldnt really need next prev, but to what you want, your better doing a standard query_posts() and include your pagination that way

Comment: I have set it up as `$the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=10&category_name=blog' );
 $myposts = get_posts('numberposts=5&category=732');` then the if nav etc, then I have `while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`.  However, the details within this second while are just those of the page.  It runs it 3 times (thats all the posts there are) but it is echoing out the page names info, the page's excerpt etc, instead of the posts I am looping through.

Comment: on your get_posts call you would need to add post_type=post otherwise it will spit out all the pages along with posts.. ;)

Comment: Thanks Marty.  It doesn't like your updated code, I get Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in C:\.....\wp-includes\query.php on line 27

Comment: I updated my code to include post_type=post, yet it still shows just the page's info I'm on when using the_title etc

Comment: hey don't worry, I just decided for the moment to not have pagination, I can always back to adding it if the client comes back and says they want it.  So as it stands your prev answer was right!